# Why is there a delay between the end time of one task and the start of the next task in SQL Server Trace

Tags: sql-server, sql-trace

We are seeing much slower performance in production vs. QA when running the same queries with basically the same data.  We have run traces with a DBA for both QA and production.  The traces don't show any issues with any of the queries.  However, I noticed there is a 0.033 delay between the end of most tasks and the start of the next task in the production traces.  I don’t see this same delay in the QA traces.  What could be causing this delay in production?  What can be done on the server to reduce this lag time between the end and start of tasks?  This is resulting in a significant delay for the users – up to 50 seconds.   Thanks.

Below is an excerpt from the production trace.  Notice the .033 delay between start and end times for most tasks

[image: Below is an excerpt from the production trace]

Below is an excerpt from the QA trace.  There is not a .033 delay between start and end times

[image]

Comment: Are they hosted in dramatically different environments? And do they have the same purge schedule? In other words, do both databases have a similar number of records?

Comment: (1) I see the same difference on both systems.  (2) 0.003 seconds is the "tick" for a `datetime`.  It is the smallest unit of increment.

Comment: QA has a few with .003 difference - however production consistently has .033 difference

Comment: Both environments are similar and both have similar number of records

Comment: Communication latency? How many hops apart are the client and server in PROD versus the client and server in QA?

Comment: I will investigate.  Thanks @AlwaysLearning